# How to log restassured request data to testNG report file

Tags: java, rest, logging, testng, rest-assured

I want to log request data which gets printed in console to testNG report file using testNG's Reporter.log() method which expects string input. Below is my request specification:

```
private RequestSpecification getRequestSpec(ContentType requestbodytype, ContentType responsetype) {

    return  RestAssured.given().log().everything().contentType(requestbodytype).accept(responsetype);
}
protected Response get(String resourceURI, ContentType requestbodytype, ContentType responsetype, boolean enableUrlEncoding) {

    Response rs = null;
    rs = getRequestSpec(requestbodytype, responsetype).when().get(resourceURI);
    Reporter.log(rs.print());
    return rs;
}
```

I want to log below content to testing log file along with response which I will receive upon exection of this call

```
Request method: GET
Request URI:    http://localhost:port/url
Proxy:          <none>
Request params: <none>
Query params:   <none>
Form params:    <none>
Path params:    <none>
Headers:        Accept=application/json, application/javascript, text/javascript
                Content-Type=application/json; charset=UTF-8
Cookies:        <none>
Multiparts:     <none>
Body:           <none>
```

Can anyone please help me to resolve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `RestAssured.config().logConfig()` and it worked fine. Now next challenge is to enable pretty print.

```
private RequestSpecification getRequestSpec(ContentType requestbodytype, ContentType responsetype, boolean urlEncodingEnabled) {
    writer = new StringWriter();
    captor = new PrintStream(new WriterOutputStream(writer), true);
    return  RestAssured.given().config(RestAssured.config().logConfig(new LogConfig(captor, true))).urlEncodingEnabled(urlEncodingEnabled).log().everything().contentType(requestbodytype).accept(responsetype);
}

protected Response get(String resourceURI, ContentType requestbodytype, ContentType responsetype, boolean urlEncodingEnabled) {
    Response rs = null;
    rs = getRequestSpec(requestbodytype, responsetype, urlEncodingEnabled).when().get(resourceURI);
    Reporter.log("---- Request ----");
    Reporter.log(writer.toString());
    Reporter.log("---- Response ----");
    Reporter.log(rs.asString());
    return rs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a filter to your requestSpecBuilder and add a Reporter.log to it.

`rSpecBuilder.addFilter( (req, response, ctx) -> {Reporter.log("Req called" + req.getDerivedPath()); return ctx.next(req, response); });`

Comment: I am sorry but are these lambda expressions in your answer? I have to use Java 1.7.0_45 only.